# New post creation page in wordpress doesn't display properly

Tags: wordpress

I am not sure if I am entitled to ask you a question.

I am creating a website by using WordPress.

When I click a New Post, the new post page doesn't display correctly. The left most side shows a list of menu text vertically. The page is not workable.

I tried using chrome, MS edge, both have same problem. I deleted cookie, caches, histories, no help.

My browsers are up-to-dated.

I tried Twenty Twenty-One. It has same issue. I haven't install any plugin.

I will appreciate you very much if you can help me for the issue.

Best regards,

Peter Shaw
[image]

Comment: i think your theme css not working properly did you change the server? or shifted website from one server to other?

Comment: It is my first time working on the website. I asked the admin of the host. They said they had downgraded my PHP version to 7.4. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The website host reconfigured my WAF by deactivating OWASP_CRS. It solved the problem.